# How do I connect to a Google Cloud MySQL database using DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I am new to Google Cloud SQL and new to DataGrip.  I've created a database in GC, but have not modified it yet.

My question is, how do I connect the two?

Specifically, what do I put in the following fields:  Host, User and URL

Is the User field my Google username?  Or something else?

Thanks in advance for helping a noob!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used DataGrip before, but my guess is that User is going to be your DB user, Host is going to be the IP for the Cloud SQL instance, and leave URL blank (it says in the UI there that it overrides other settings, so you shouldn't need it).

My suggestion would be to setup the Cloud SQL proxy (documentation on how to do so can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy). The proxy is a binary that you'll run locally with DataGrip that will handle the communication between you and Cloud SQL.

It will walk you through setting up the proxy, which then will allow you to put 'localhost' in that Host field, while still securely connecting to your Cloud SQL instance without having to worry about other settings. If you don't do it, then you'll need to authorize the IP address of where you're connecting from in the Cloud SQL settings which is less secure.

Comment: You are very close, but not quite correct.  Thank you for taking the time to reply though!!  I put my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out, and thought someone out there might find my solution useful.

Host:

The IP for your server: SQL > Overview > Connect to this instance > Public IP Address

User: root

Password: password for your database

URL: jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xxx.xx:zzzz (x's are your IP, z's are your port number)

Comment: Hello, in my case Datagrip return error "Connection timed out: connect". Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Read [DataGrip official documentation about MySQL connections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-mysql-database)